# Is RandomGraph really random?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

I think there are 2 non-Hamiltonian graphs with 5 vertices and exactly 7 edges.  There are a total of 4 graphs with 5 vertices and 7 edges.  If I run (in version 9):

```
n = 5;
Count[Table[HamiltonianGraphQ[
   RandomGraph[{n, Binomial[n - 1, 2] + 1}]], {1000000}], False]
```

Mathematica returns about 250000.  I was expecting about half a million.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Indeed there are four graphs with 5 vertices and 7 edges, two of which have a Hamiltonian cycle:

```
TableForm[{#, HamiltonianGraphQ@#} & /@ 
  DeleteDuplicates[
    RandomGraph[{n, Binomial[n - 1, 2] + 1}, 1000], 
    IsomorphicGraphQ
  ], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"Graph", "HamiltonianGraphQ"}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, `RandomGraph` doesn't sample from that space, but from a larger space that includes many graphs that are isomorphic to each other. If you examine some of the graphs they look identical but under the hood they are different:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Draw 10,000 random graphs and tally taking isomorphism into account and you get this:

```
Tally[RandomGraph[{n, Binomial[n - 1, 2] + 1}, 10000], IsomorphicGraphQ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see the graphs with a Hamiltonian cycle are not available in this set in the same amount as the graphs without such a cycle, hence your results.

In fact, there are a total of 120 different graphs with the 5,7 property:

```
RandomGraph[{n, Binomial[n - 1, 2] + 1}, 100000] // Union // Length
```

`120`

with isomorphicity distributed as follows:

```
Tally[RandomGraph[{n, Binomial[n - 1, 2] + 1}, 100000] // Union, IsomorphicGraphQ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The non-Hamiltonions make up precisely 1/4 of the set. This is consistent with your results.

Comment: It samples from the set of *labelled graphs* (vertices are considered distinguishable). Essentially, each entry in the adjacency matrix is an independent random variable.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's in short what I'm saying above, right?

Comment: Yes, I just gave you the technical term.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, for a moment I wasn't entirely sure whether it was an addition or a correction.